# Calculating Non-Power of Two values for flag enumeration

Tags: c#, enums

I have a Flag Enumeration

```
[Flag] 
public enum Enumeration{
      None
      Method1
      Method2
      Method4
}
```

I would like to calculate "missing" values for example, in the above enumeration, I would need to find

- "Method1AndMethod2" (Method 3).
- "Method1AndMethod4" (Method 5).
- "Method2AndMethod4" (Method 6).
- "Method1Method2AndMethod4" (Method 7).

  What would be the easiest way to do this for a Flag Enum?

I have already determined which enumerations in an assembly are flags.so I would just need a method to go through and calculate the missing values.

Comment: Did you intend to assign the value `4` to `Method4`? Right now it has the value `3`, and your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: The values in the actual enum are set to powers of two.

Comment: Enumeration.Method1 & Enumeration.Method2 Won't work If I don't know what values are in the enumeration beforehand. The above was just an example of what I need to do. This program runs on a CI build server. Right now it can print a list of the Enums as they are in the code. but I need to calculate all possible concatenations of methods. This would also have to work if more flag enumerations are added.

If I could figure out the Maximum value in the [Flags] Enumeration, I could then calculate the rest of the values.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to scan an assembly (via reflection, some kind of FxCop style thing?) and find any `Flags` enum that doesn't have a *named* value for any particular combination?

Comment: I am already scanning the assembly using reflection. That sounds about right. I need to look at the values that are there, and calculate the ones that arent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work without the powers of two explicitly defined as the values of your enum. `Flags` attribute in itself only affects the string representation of the enumeration (e.g. when calling `yourEnumerationValue.ToString()`). So first:

```
[Flags] 
public enum Enumeration{
      None = 1,
      Method1 = 2,
      Method2 = 4,
      Method4 = 8
      // etc.
}
```

By the way, it's `Flags`, not `Flag`.

When you have it set up this way, you use bitwise operations. Use bitwise OR to make a "sum" of your enumeration items

```
Enumeration method3 = Enumeration.Method1 | Enumeration.Method2;
```

If you want to check if some Enumeration value contains Method1 and/or Method2, you do it like this:

```
Enumeration someValue = // whatever value you want here
bool containsMethod1 = someValue & Enumeration.Method1 == Enumeration.Method1;
bool containsMethod2 = someValue & Enumeration.Method2 == Enumeration.Method2;
bool containsBoth = someValue & method3 == method3;
```

On the other hand you can't really have "Method1AndMethod2". They are separate things, so Method1 does not equal Method2 unless you assign them the same values, but then they would just be aliases for each other.

**EDIT**: since .NET 4.0 there's an easier way to check if an enumeration value contains a flag:

```
bool containsMethod1 = someValue.HasFlag(Enumeration.Method1);
bool containsBoth = someValue.HasFlag(method3);
// or .HasFlag(Enumeration.Method1 | Enumeration.Method2)
```

And here's a simple solution writing all missing values from provided MyEnum enumeration to console:

```
[Flags]
enum MyEnum
{
    Manual = 1,
    Site = 2,
    Api = 4,
    Custom = 8
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // SortedSet is not necessary but it has convenient Min and Max properties.
    SortedSet<MyEnum> enumValues = new SortedSet<MyEnum>();

    foreach (MyEnum e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)))
        enumValues.Add(e);

    // enumValues.Max * 2 to check all combinations including the last flag.
    for (int i = (int)enumValues.Min + 1; i < (int)enumValues.Max * 2; i++)
    {
        MyEnum currentlyChecked = (MyEnum)i;

        // if there's no equivalent of i defined in MyEnum
        if (!enumValues.Contains(currentlyChecked))
        {
            string representation = "";

            // Iterate over all MyEnum flags which underlying value is lower than i
            // and add those flags which are contained in (MyEnum)i to the string representation
            // of the value missing from the MyEnum enumeration.
            foreach (MyEnum lowerValue in enumValues.Where(e => (int)e < i))
            {
                if (currentlyChecked.HasFlag(lowerValue))
                    representation += lowerValue.ToString();
            }

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(representation))
                representation = "[MISSING FLAG]";

            Console.WriteLine("Missing value: {0} - {1}", i, representation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: They are explicitly defined, I just messed up the example.

for example, if my Enumeration contains the following

`-Manual = 1`
`-Site = 2`
`-API = 4`

I need to calculate

`-ManualSite = 3`
`-ManualAPI = 5`
`-SiteAPI = 6`
`-ManualSiteApi = 7`

Comment: I use `1<<0`, `1<<1`, `1<<2`, `1<<3`, `1<<4`, ... for the values instead of `1,2,4,8,16,..` because it is easier when you have many fields.

Comment: I don't see how this helps with `need a method to go through and calculate the missing values`.

Comment: @user3500033 I've added a simple code in answer to your comment, I hope that solves your problem.

Comment: This code only works if you know they type of the enumeration. During runtime, the enumerations are grabbed from an assembly. How would I modify this code to work when the enumeration type isn't known?